# A question about the Dirac operator and zero modes in the book "Mirror Symmetry" by Clay Institute

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-anomalies, mirror-symmetry

I have a question about the book "Mirror Symmetry" p.296~298.

Using the notations there, the Dirac operator and its conjugate are denoted as $D_z$ and $D_{\overline{z}}$. In p.297, the book assumes that $D_{\overline{z}}$ has $k$ zero modes while $D_z$ has no zero modes, for the index $k$.

Then, it claims that the correlation function
\begin{equation}
\langle \psi_-(z_1) \cdots \psi_-(z_k) \overline{\psi}_+(w_1) \cdots \overline{\psi}_+(w_k) \rangle
\end{equation}
is nonvanishing. This is the equation (13.39) of the book. But I do not understand. Why does the absence of zero modes for $D_z$ imply that the above correlation function is nonzero?

Also, in p.298, the book says the same claim may be made in the case where $D_z$ has zero modes as well. I do not see how this can be done either.

In short, what does the zero mode of the Dirac operator have to do with the vanishing of the correlation functions?

Could anyone please explain more in detail?

Comment: basically this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/433199/84967

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what the book is doing, but in calculating correlators of Fermi fields interacting with a  dynamical background gauge or gravitational field  the Green functions of the Fermions in a given backround field configuration have to be weighted  by the Dirac determinant for that configuration. If there are $k$ zero modes then  the Fermion determinant has $k$ factors of zero. To get a non-zero answer for a correlator these zeros have to be cancelled by  $k$ factors of zero in the denominators of the Fermion Green functions. You therefore need $k$ $\bar\psi$'s and $k$ $\psi$'s in the correlators.

You may find the discussion in [this](http://people.physics.illinois.edu/stone/toy_instanton.pdf) essay to be of use.